# Why does Mick just let the last victim shown leave, when he was already captured?

Tags: plot-explanation, wolf-creek-2

One thing I just don't get about *Wolf Creek 2*, and about Mick Taylor the character, is how he just lets the one guy go after capturing him. Then he apparently undresses him and drops him off at a random street in the city with a note saying "LOSER". Okay? I certainly would prefer that a million times over spending months before getting fully killed in his horror dungeon...

This behaviour goes completely against both the established mentality of Mick Taylor as well as all logic.

He is an extremely sadistic and crazy man who has apparently hundreds upon hundreds of victims, having turned many of their bodies into bizarre "ornaments", and loves to torture them for months before killing them in his dungeons.

Yet, after "simply" cutting off two fingers from the guy, he chases him for fun in a casual manner, knowing that there is no escape once his victims get down there, but afterwards, he would normally secure the victim and continue torturing them when they wake up the next time. Instead, he dangerously risks his entire "operation" by allowing a victim to escape.

The guy managed to piss him off (which is easily done), and it's been established in many scenes that as soon as you tick him off, you are *going* to be horribly tortured and murdered. Yet, even with the guy helpless and already in his dungeon, he goes out of his way with this particular person to drive him into town, risk getting seen by somebody, and even leaves a hand-written note which may have fingerprints or his DNA on it.

It just makes no sense. So why did he?